# How to create main activity with list of ImageButton

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app.
In my first activity I want to create a list of button like this:

[image]

So I have build this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ButtonArticoli"
                android:layout_width="150px"
                android:layout_height="150px"
                android:onClick="visualizzaArticoli"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/articoli"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewArticoli"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/articoli"
                android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonCreateOrder"
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:onClick="creaOrdine"
            android:src="@drawable/order"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ordini"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Prima Riga -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonClienti"
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:onClick="viewClienti"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/customer"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cliente"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonAlignDatabase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="allineaDatase"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/sincronizza"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/allinea_database"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonSetting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="setting"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/setting"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/impostazioni"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

But the result of my app when I try yo start my application is this:
[image]

Can we help me?

Comment: You should use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to dynamically create a list of views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code if you have a fixed size of elements.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#F1C983">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#D9EE9A">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#D9EE9A">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#D9EE9A">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Use `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'` to get the `CardView`.

[image: Here]

this is the sample output.

Answer (score 0):

use ListView or RecyclerView with your custom list item which will contain image buttons and custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `px` use `dp` it´s much better!
2. If you want a fixed list, your XML is correct, but if you want a dynamic list, you should use `ListView` or `RecycleView` , as the others users said.
3. The weight in your `LinearLayout` is wrong, weight should be used when you desires your screen to fit in every screen, no matter the size ( and you will need to "distribute" your weigth throught the children´s).
4. To make your screen similar to the first image, you need to set a background in your second `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Okey this a recyclerview for what you want,

```
public class MainPageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainPageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private @DrawableRes int[] iconDrawables;
    private String[] texts;


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.img_lockIcon.setImageResource(iconDrawables[position]);
        holder.txt_whatever.setText(texts[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return iconDrawables != null ? iconDrawables.length : 0;
    }

    public void setData(@DrawableRes int[] iconDrawables, String[] texts){
        this.iconDrawables = iconDrawables;
        this.texts = texts;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView img_icon;
        TextView txt_whatever;
        ImageView img_lockIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img_icon);
            txt_whatever = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txt_whatever);
            img_lockIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img_lockIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

this is R.layout.item,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img_icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_txt_whatever"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        tools:text="YouTube"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img_lockIcon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and below is MainActivity layout,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and below is MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        MainPageAdapter adapter = new MainPageAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Set your data
        //adapter.setData();
    }
}
```

You can change color as you want and also notify that ı used two different arrays for adapter but you can use pojo classes also. Hope this helps you.